# How to spawn a chicken that lays diamonds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to make a chicken drop something else instead of an egg by using commands? I've tried the following:

```
/summon Chicken ~  ~ ~ {Drop:[{id:diamond}]}
```

It said "Object succesfully summoned", but the chicken still dropped an egg.
**So, what is the command needed for spawning a chicken that lays diamonds?**

Answer (score 8):

There is no simple command to do this, but I have found a way to replace eggs that were just laid by a chicken with a diamond.

This makes use of the chicken's [`EggLayTime`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chicken#Data_values) data tag, to mark chickens which are about to lay an egg. Unfortunately, this tag never actually *reaches* 0, it resets immediately. So, marking them 1 tick before will have to suffice. Create a scoreboard objective for the chickens:

```
/scoreboard objectives add eggLayer dummy
```

Now set up a repeat/chain command block line, and put in the following commands:

```
/scoreboard players remove @e[type=Chicken,score_eggLayer_min=1] eggLayer 1
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Chicken] eggLayer 2 {EggLayTime:1}
/execute @e[type=Chicken,score_eggLayer=1,score_eggLayer_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players tag @e[type=Item,c=1,r=1] add laidEgg {Item:{id:minecraft:egg}}
/entitydata @e[type=Item,tag=laidEgg] {Item:{id:minecraft:diamond},Tags:[]}
```

Chickens that will lay an egg in 1 tick get an `eggLayer` score of 2, which automatically decreased by 1 per tick until it reaches 0 again. 1 tick later, when the egg is actually laid, it is marked with a tag and transformed into a diamond using `/entitydata`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/summon Chicken ~0 ~1 ~0 {Equipment:[{Count:1,id:whatever},{},{},{},{}],DropChances:[2.0F,0.0F,0.0F,0.0F,0.0F]}
```

The chicken will drop the item listed as `whatever` whenever it's killed.

Comment: This will make the chicken drop the item when killed, but not lay it as it lays an egg (which seems to be what OP wants).